# How I can animate this diamond image so it looks as 3d diamond is rotating downward?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to animate this diamond
[diamong images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HplbX.png)
in such a way it look like a real diamond is rotating.
As a 3d diamond is rotating downward. Please help me it means a lot.
Thanks.

[what i try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHt9l.png)

[animation is used in second section of website](https://www.jamesallen.com/)

```
<section class="relative flex items-center justify-center w-screen h-screen bg-gray-600">
    <div class="absolute w-40 h-20 top-28" >
        <div class="">
            <img  class="ml-3 w-36 diamond_animtion"  src="fake/diamond.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <img class="absolute ml-12 top-14" style="width: 70px;" src="fake/Prong.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <img class="w-96 h-96" src="fake/ring.png" alt="">
</section>
```

[how i can slow down animation speed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBodY.png)

Comment: Yes we will surely keen to help you but providing a code really means a lot to us. It gives a starting point to us and tells that how much effort you have don to solve it.

Comment: @Rana I have just added code and what I try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the trick using css overflow and background position, then use JS to make it move.

```js
let height = 0,
  steps = 0;
const animation = setInterval((function() {
  height += 290.35, document.getElementById("diamond").style.backgroundPosition = `0px -${height}px`, 18 == steps++ && clearInterval(animation)
}), 42);

//With scroll
```

```css
#diamond {
  height: 290px;
  width: 351px;
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/HplbX.png') 0px 0px;
  background-size: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="diamond">
</div>
```

According to your example, here's could be a solution to animate diamond when scroll.

**NOTE:** This solution is not suitable for production because of scroll steps glitch but you can use it and modify to fit your needs

```js
let bounding,
  height = 145, //Equal your diamond CSS height
  topPos = 0,
  scrollPos = 0,
  steps = 0,
  diamond = document.getElementById("diamond");

function scrollDiamond(o) {
  "down" === o && steps < 18 ? (act = `0px -${topPos+=height}px`, steps++) : "up" === o && steps > -1 && (act = `0px -${topPos-=height}px`, steps--)
  diamond.style.backgroundPosition = act;
}
window.addEventListener("scroll", (function() {
  bounding = document.body.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  bounding > scrollPos ? scrollDiamond("up") : scrollDiamond("down"), scrollPos = bounding
}));
```

```css
body {
  height: 200vh;
}

#diamond {
  position: fixed;
  /* Your image heigh divided by 40 (or whatever you want) */
  height: 145px;
  width: 175px;
  /* Your image width divided by 40 (or whatever you want)*/
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/HplbX.png') 0px 0px/100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="diamond"></div>
```

Comment: Can It Animate with page, scroll?
If you are busy so just give me hint I'll make it myself?

Comment: why animation break down when i'll change the width of  of div
#diamond

Comment: What if I want to change the width of diamond size?
Basically, I am learning web development.
So as a practice I'll make the clone of this website https://www.jamesallen.com/ the front page is almost ready butt the animation in second section make difficulties.

Comment: You must divide by 20 the height of your diamond image (all diamons) to get the new size to add/remove, I've edited with other size take a look. You must keep the ratio of your image

Comment: Bro the second code you provide is fit for my animation just tell me that how can I slow down the speed of animation and everthing is working perfactly allright.
I just have add the code image in last of my question.

Comment: @UmairMustafa you must think about percentage of page scroll, it may be what you searching for. Try to make it yourself, and open a new question if this one is answered. Now you need something like ***"How to syncrhonise background position according to page scroll"*** If my answer work for you, dont hesitate to accept it. I repeat try by yourself and come back to us. Happy coding

Comment: I'll try a lot, but I am not success full. I am not very much good in javascript, so it's a little difficult for me please tell me how I'll slow down the speed of animation.
Thanks

Comment: Share what you tried with community, you can open a new question if needed.